# HOW to fix pip3 intall pygdal==2.2.3.3 or pip3 install pygdal sent this error

Tags: python-3.6, gdal, python-3.7

error
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-w_pz3 u2e\pygdal\

i try to install pygdal package i have always the same error 
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\bough\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-w_pz3
u2e\pygdal\

python 3.6  python 3.7 the same error always

EDIT: Complete Error Text

> e4cb71f72e29da0c25a1ea9135596a577/pygdal-2.2.3.3.tar.gz  Complete
>   output from command python setup.py  egg_info: running egg_info
>   creating pip-egg-info\pygdal.egg-info writing
>   pip-egg-info\pygdal.egg-info\PKG-INFO writing dependency_links to
>   pip-egg-info\pygdal.egg-info\dependency_links.txt writing requirements
>   to pip-egg-info\pygdal.egg-info\requires.txt writing top-level names
>   to pip-egg-info\pygdal.egg-info\top_level.txt writing manifest file
>   'pip-egg-info\pygdal.egg-info\SOURCES.txt' error: [WinError 2] The
>   system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Is the `error code 1` the only error message?

Comment: with error code 1

Comment: pip install pygdal==2.2.3.3 
error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
............................................................................................................................
Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at 'C:\Users\bough\nuages\Scripts\python.exe'.
.................................................................................................................................

Comment: pip install pygdal==2.2.3.3 
error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\bough\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygdal\

Comment: Collecting pygdal==2.2.3.3
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/95/0d/bfc6150ac1ce710206b33111c01

Comment: e4cb71f72e29da0c25a1ea9135596a577/pygdal-2.2.3.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info\pygdal.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info\pygdal.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\pygdal.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to pip-egg-info\pygdal.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\pygdal.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\pygdal.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: I am too lazy to write this as an answer as I will have to copy and paste the snippets from the source I wrote so lets this be a comment. Go to this link on my [github](https://github.com/felipunky/GISPython), I don't know if it works with python 3, but it sure does with python 2.